# Postfix: no llegan a hotmail, pero si cuando respondo

Tags: linux, email, server, dovecot, postfix

Tengo un problema curioso con **Postfix** y las cuentas hotmail.com. outlook.com, etc.

**Problema:** Mis dominios no pueden enviar "nuevos" correos a hotmail. O sea, envia pero no llegan nunca y los log no tiran errores. Los correos que recibo de hotmail y los respondo, esos si llegan.

**Descarto situaciones:** A gmail.com, yahoo.com y otras cuentas todo funciona perfecto (recibo/envio). Desde webmail o clientes como Thunderbird, MS Outlook es lo mismo. La IP **NO** esta bloqueada por Spam. Los certificados estan perfectamente instalados y pasan todos los chequeos dkim, spf, dmarc marcan OK (incluso en hotmail). Recibo correos perfectamente.

Los sistemas que uso son: **opendkim** (hotmail esta agregado como TRUSTED HOSTS), **dovecot**, **postfix**, **sendmail**.

Esto devuelve **maillog**

```
May 23 21:54:11 server postfix/smtp[27396]: 81FA6463DC1: to=<xxxx@outlook.com>, relay=outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.6.33]:25, delay=4.6, delays=0.04/0.01/2.2/2.3, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20200524005406.81FA6463DC1@miservidor.com> [InternalId=83790516991860, Hostname=VE1EUR02HT096.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com] 7145 bytes in 0.980, 7.113 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery -> 250 2.1.5)
May 23 21:54:11 server postfix/qmgr[7087]: 81FA6463DC1: removed
```

Simplemente no se me ocurre que debería mirar. Alguien me podría orientar?

**Actualización:**
Se me ocurrió enviar un correo a una cuenta de correo de hotmail marcando en el webmail que me envie "un estado de la entrega". El reporte es algo como esto...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]